# Replacing elements of column names with associated strings

Tags: r, data.table, r-colnames

I have a data.table with automatically generated column names. The names take the form:

N.x.y.z

Where N is a character (literally N), and the remaining variables are integers.

I also have a .csv which associates iterations of x with meaningful strings. As in:

| X | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Model |
| 3 | Mileage |

What I would like to do is regenerate the column names in the format:

N.Name.y.z

I've tried to work along the lines of extracting the column names first, like

```
thefile = fread('filepath')

xx <- colnames(thefile)

colindex <- read.csv('the other file path')
colindex[,1] <- paste0('N.', colindex[,1], '.') #Converting x to N.x.
```

I messed around with grepl, replace_at, splitting the string up by '.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
read.table(text = "X    Name
                   1    Model
                   3    Mileage", 
           header = T, stringsAsFactor = FALSE) -> colindex


df1 <- data.frame(`N.1.2.3` = c(1,2), `N.3.1.2` = c(6,5), 
                  `N.1.3.1` = c(3, 4), `N.3.2.2` = c(8, 7))

df1
#>   N.1.2.3 N.3.1.2 N.1.3.1 N.3.2.2
#> 1       1       6       3       8
#> 2       2       5       4       7

names_split <-  as.data.frame(strsplit(names(df1), "\\."))
names_split[2,] <-  colindex[match(names_split[2,], colindex$X), "Name"]
names(df1) <- apply(names_split, 2, paste, collapse = ".")

df1
#>   N.Model.2.3 N.Mileage.1.2 N.Model.3.1 N.Mileage.2.2
#> 1           1             6           3             8
#> 2           2             5           4             7
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Yes that works, thank you. I probably read the documentation incorrectly, but I though match would find you the first instance of a match rather than all instances, but it finds all instances here.

Answer (score 2):

Another option (using @M--'s data) is to use `stringr`:

```r
stringr::str_replace_all(
  names(df1),
  setNames(paste0("N.", colindex$Name), paste0("N\\.", colindex$X)))
# [1] "N.Model.2.3"   "N.Mileage.1.2" "N.Model.3.1"   "N.Mileage.2.2"
```

(and reassigning those back with `names(df1) <-`)

This approach is a bit specific to having what you want be exactly next to the literal `N.`. It can be adapted to other positions if need be, with slight mods to the pattern.

A base-R version could be:

```r
gre <- gregexpr("(?<=N[.])([0-9]+)(?=[.])", names(df1), perl = TRUE)
regmatches(names(df1), gre) <- colindex$Name[match(unlist(regmatches(names(df1), gre)), colindex$X)]
df1
#   N.Model.2.3 N.Mileage.1.2 N.Model.3.1 N.Mileage.2.2
# 1           1             6           3             8
# 2           2             5           4             7
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Could I ask a tangential question; how important is regex to R? It's not something I've had to use before using a particular application of Matlab.

Comment: Does Matlab do dynamic string modification with some other type of expression? Regex is a language/construct of its own, certainly not unique to R. As with other constructs, it is very efficient for many things and mis-used on others.

Comment: It might, but I didn't have to use it, I mostly did array calculations so never needed to do anything complicated with strings. Since I'm going to be using R more for things with mixes of numeric and text data, I'm wondering if getting familiar with regex is going to help a lot, or is it more occasionally useful.

Comment: Like I said, regex is a tool to be used. It is not specific to R ... apparently, [matlab does regex as well](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html). Regex does some things really well, and other things it is not at all well-suited for (e.g., [not HTML parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3358272)).The world of regex can be magical, and when used correctly it is great, but in some situations it is not the best (performance, stability, etc). I'm not saying regex is the magical elixir, just that it can be used safely _here_.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table::setnames`, split column names on `"."`, then paste it back together replacing the 2nd item from the lookup:

```
library(data.table)

lookup <- fread(text = "X    Name
                   1    Model
                   3    Mileage", 
           header = T, stringsAsFactor = FALSE)
# convert to named vector
lookup <- setNames(lookup$Name, lookup$X)

dt <- data.table(`N.1.2.3` = c(1,2), `N.3.1.2` = c(6,5), 
                 `N.1.3.1` = c(3, 4), `N.3.2.2` = c(8, 7))

setnames(dt, 
         new = sapply(strsplit(colnames(dt), ".", fixed = TRUE), function(i){
           paste(i[ 1 ], lookup[ i[ 2 ] ], i[ 3 ], i[ 4 ], sep = ".") } ))
dt

#      N.Model.2.3 N.Mileage.1.2 N.Model.3.1 N.Mileage.2.2
#           <num>         <num>       <num>         <num>
# 1:           1             6           3             8
# 2:           2             5           4             7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
rename_with(df1, ~str_replace(.x, "\\d", ~deframe(colindex)[.x]))

  N.Model.2.3 N.Mileage.1.2 N.Model.3.1 N.Mileage.2.2
1           1             6           3             8
2           2             5           4             7
```

---

Other options:

```
rename_with(df1,~str_replace_all(.x,deframe(map(colindex, ~str_c('N.', .x)))))

  N.Model.2.3 N.Mileage.1.2 N.Model.3.1 N.Mileage.2.2
1           1             6           3             8
2           2             5           4             7
```

---

base R:

```
fn <- \(x,y)sub(sprintf("(?<=N.)%s", y[1]), y[2], x, perl = TRUE)
setNames(df1, Reduce(fn, asplit(colindex, 1), names(df1)))

  N.Model.2.3 N.Mileage.1.2 N.Model.3.1 N.Mileage.2.2
1           1             6           3             8
2           2             5           4             7
```

---

Data:

```
colindex <- read.table(text = "X    Name
                   1    Model
                   3    Mileage", 
           header = T, stringsAsFactor = FALSE) 


df1 <- data.frame(`N.1.2.3` = c(1,2), `N.3.1.2` = c(6,5), 
                  `N.1.3.1` = c(3, 4), `N.3.2.2` = c(8, 7))
```